# How do I get my product pages to all have the one column layout?

Tags: magento-2.1, xml

I only use simple products. Some of my product pages are set to one column and some are set to 2 columns right. I want all of them set to one column. I have a child theme that uses the **catalog_product_view.xml**. I have used to move blocks around, and everything works. I added layout="1column" to the page so it looks like this

```
page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
```

And it doesn't work. I have flushed the cache but it hasn't made any difference. How can I set all product pages to just use one column layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set product page one column with using below options in your child theme :

> 1) Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

> 2) From Admin panel :-
>   **Product -> Catalog -> Edit Product -> Design -> Layout option**

You need to check in admin panel for that particular product which layout is different from 1 column & **select no layout update** value because it will override catalog_product_view.xml settings.

Comment: I did set it to the 1 column and it didn't help. I went to where you said and it was set to the wrong layout, I switched it and it fixed it. I ran across this -https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166583/force-product-view-layout-to-1column and he was having the same issue and it was due to the migration. I want to check the database like he did but don't have the reputation to ask him which table it is. Do you happen to know?